# Playing video stored in S3 or Dropbox in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, dropbox

I uploaded an audio file to Dropbox and put a link to it in my Rails application. When I clicked the link, it automatically opened an audio player.  However, when I tried the same with video, it didn't work, either in S3 or Dropbox (which uses S3). Is there a way to play video from Dropbox or S3 in a Rails application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason the audio file opened in the browser and not the video is more a function of your browser and not your Rails app. If you want to control the display of those things you will need to use `<video>` tags for videos, and `<audio>` tags for audio. You can find references for both of those [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp).